# Awk how to change a word but not every instance of the letter

Tags: awk

I wrote an AWK program to change `i` to `I` and `awk` to `AWK`. It works but it also changes every word containing `i` to and a `I`. So `writing` will be changed to `wrItIng`.

How do I make it just change the word `i` to `I`?

Here is my program:

```
'{gsub(/i/, "I");gsub(/awk/, "AWK");print}'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [`gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), the word-boundary operator `\y` is available, so you can search for `\yi\y`.

```
# without \y
$ echo 'i use gawk, which is acronym for gnu awk' | awk '{gsub(/i/, "I");gsub(/awk/, "AWK");print}'
I use gAWK, whIch Is acronym for gnu AWK
# with \y
$ echo 'i use gawk, which is acronym for gnu awk' | awk '{gsub(/\yi\y/, "I");gsub(/\yawk\y/, "AWK");print}'
I use gawk, which is acronym for gnu AWK
```

Normally, the word-boundary in regular expression is `\b` but not in gawk: as stated in [Gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html),

> that conflicts with the awk language's definition of ‘\b’ as
>   backspace, so gawk uses a different letter. An alternative method
>   would have been to require two backslashes in the GNU operators, but
>   this was deemed too confusing. The current method of using ‘\y’ for
>   the GNU ‘\b’ appears to be the lesser of two evils.

This feature is not supported in [`mawk`](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/).

Comment: I verified on a fresh ubuntu 12.04 box and it does not work: default `awk` is provided by `mawk` which has less features than `gawk`. AFAIK `mawk` does not have word-boundary operators (`\<`, `\>` and `\y`). So two options: install `gawk` to provide a more powerful `awk` command, or use `sed` or `perl` as proposed in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using GNU `awk`, that support `egrep` expressions so you probably want to use the word boundaries `\<` and `\>`:

```
pax> echo "Know that i am alive" | awk '{gsub(/\<i\>/,"I");print}'
Know that I am alive

pax> echo "awk is good to gawk at" | awk '{gsub(/\<awk\>/,"AWK");print}'
AWK is good to gawk at
```

Comment: I also tried using \< \> and did not work I'm using ubuntu 12.04lts. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Simple enough fix, either make sure you install `gawk` or upgrade to Debian :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think for this it can be better to use `sed`:

```
$ echo "heilo i aia"  | sed -r 's/(\s)i(\s)/\1I\2/g'
heilo I aia
```

- `sed s/hello/bye/g` replaces all `hello` with `bye`.
- `-r` allows to catch groups with simple `()`.
- `(\s)i(\s)` catches "spaces" (tab, space...) then the letter `i` and "spaces" again.
- `\1I\2` prints them back.

With the `awk` part:

```
$ echo "heilo i aia this awk is awkward"  | sed -r -e 's/(\s)i(\s)/\1I\2/g' -e 's/(\s)awk(\s)/\1AWK\2/g'
heilo I aia this AWK is awkward
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably perl is a better choice for this.

```
perl -pe 's/\bi\b/I/g;s/\b\awk\b/AWK/g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `gawk` you could try

```
{
    gsub(/ i /," I ")
    sub(/ i$/," I")
    sub(/^i $/,"I ")
    print
}
```